# Generating a random value array without repeating

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to make a method that generates an array with random values between 0 and 6 in it without repeating those values.

This is what I've got:

```
void randomArray(){

randNum = rand() % 6;
code[0] = randNum

for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){

  randNum = rand() % 6;
  code[i] = randNum;

  while (code[i] == code[i - 1]){
  randNum = rand() % 6;
  code[i] = randNum;
  }
 }
}
```

But I'm getting repeated values on the random-generated array.

PD: I also need to use a similar method to make an array of enum's.

Comment: You're checking `code[i]` againts previous `code[i - 1]`, but what about `code[i - 2]`,..., `code[0]`?

Comment: You don't want random values.  You want one of a set of fixed values to be selected at random and then removed from the set.  Put the set of values in an array and index it at random, then move stuff about so you have an array one element smaller, containing the remaining values.

Comment: Create vector of values from 0 to 5 and shuffle it

Comment: rand()%6 does not produce good random numbers. (Not that that matters here.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
int randomFromSet(std::vector<int>&_set)
{
    int randIndex = rand() % _set.size();
    int num = _set[randIndex];
    _set.erase(_set.begin() + randIndex);
    return num;
}
```

This chooses a random int from a provided set of numbers, and removes that choice from the set so that it can't be picked again.
Used like so:

```
std::vector<int> mySet {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
std::cout<<randomFromSet(mySet)<<'\n;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    const int sz = 7;
    std::vector<int> nums(sz);
    std::iota(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums), 0);

    std::default_random_engine re;

    int i = 8;
    while(--i > 0) {
        auto my_set{ nums };
        std::shuffle(my_set.begin(), my_set.end(), re);

        for (auto x : my_set) {
            cout << x << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im new to c++ , can I add my answer too?
its c-style c++ sorry for that.but its easy to code and to understand at the same time.

```
#include <iostream> //std::cout
#include <ctime> //time() function
#include <cstdlib> //rand() and srand() functions

void rand_gen(unsigned int arr[],unsigned int sizeofarray)
{
srand((unsigned int)time(0);

for (unsigned int c = sizeofarray ; c > 0 ; c--)
{
unsigned int r = rand()%sizeofarray;

if (arr[r] != 404)
{

std::cout<<"Try No."<<(sizeofarray+1)-c<<" : "<<arr[r]<<"\n";

arr[r] = 404;

} else {  c++;   }
}
}

int main()
{
unsigned int n[7]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6};

rand_gen(n,7);

std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```